# Gluten free bread initially rises but collapses into itself later

Tags: bread, gluten-free

I've noticed that the gluten free bread I make in the breadmaker does reach the size of the gluten one but later ends up collapsing into itself later.

I've tried to make this recording of the process which seems to show some specific points in the process:

1. In the raising phase the dough reaches a maximum size after which it goes int the cycle of fall-raise
2. Once the baking phase starts the bread keeps on shrinking continually

There seems to be a general consensus about "gluten-free bread not raising as good as wheat bread because it doesn't have the gluten to keep the structure together". However the video I made seems to show that the gluten-free bread does seem to be able to set up the initial structure but fails to maintain it during baking.

Recipe:

- 2dl hot water
- 1.8dl oat milk
- 7g sugar
- 5g of salt
- 10g [psylium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psyllium) (this was a suggestion for hardening the structure in lack of gluten)
- 5g olive oil
- 165g buckwheat flour
- 150g rice flour
- 25g oat flour
- 60g corn flour
- Egg
- [In the dispenser, added after mixing] 5g dry yeast

I'm hoping to see if this the actual behavior of gluten-free bread when people say "gluten-free bread doesn't raise" (but what it's actually doing is raising and later falling)?

Is there perhaps a remedy?

[image]

Comment: I don't know if it'll help, but there's an earlier question about gluten free bread not rising in general, and one of the people answering specifically mentioned [what they do for their bread machine](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/40879/67)

Comment: We need the recipe for your bread.